# In a tangled heap?

Tags: vocabulary, idioms

> August lashed out with the hand that held the flashlight, hitting him
>   on the chin and sending him to the floor **in a tangled heap**. 
>   Timing, everything was timing.

What does "in a tangled heap" mean?

The definitions of *heap* found in the dictionary don't seem to apply to things like people. From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/heap):

> **heap** (*noun*)
>   1. a collection of articles or mass of material gathered together in one place
>   2. (often plural) usually foll by of (informal) a large number or quantity
>   3. (informal) a place or thing that is very old, untidy, unreliable, etc   ⇒ *the car was a heap*

Comment: BTW, please give a question at least 24 hours for responses before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. More info is [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a pile of rope that was thrown into a corner, FLOP. It's not coiled nicely. It's tangled. It's in a heap, lying upon itself.

If a person is in a tangled heap, they have fallen awkwardly and their limbs are under each other or even twisted under their body.

Comment: True, although any clumsy landing on the butt might be classified as "landing in a tangled heap." The language is more figurative than literal.

Comment: That's true -- the idiom mostly indicates a clumsy landing, where getting up again will be awkward.

Comment: I'd be inclined towards simply slipping on ice & landing seated rather painfully wouldn't qualify as a 'tangled heap' - but going completely base over apex down a hill would.

Comment: Any answer that can legitimately include onomatopoeia is a good answer.